# Leaflet: How to remove or change GeoJSON.AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet, geojson

I've added *leaflet.ajax.min.js* to my Leaflat map. On a click in the map, I'm loading a dynamically create GeoJSON from my server.

But how can I clean the layer before displaying an object? I only want to display ONE geo-object... Right now, they're added to the layer :(

```
function onMapClick(e) {
    var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("http://127.0.0.1:8000/?c=" + JSON.stringify({x: e.latlng.lng, y: e.latlng.lat }));
    geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
};
```

Comment: why aren't you using the L.control.layers for this? It offers you to select layers exclusive. Grüße Aydin

Answer (score 0):

Use `map.removeLayer(geojsonLayer)` before setting the variable to a new geoJson object

Comment: I tried this, but couldn't get it to work: `function onMapClick(e) {
    if (map.hasLayer(geojsonLayer)) {
       map.removeLayer(geojsonLayer);
    }

    var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("http://127.0.0.1:8000/?c=" + JSON.stringify({x: e.latlng.lng, y: e.latlng.lat }));
    geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
};` Or is it more efficient to just clean the layer instead of removing and adding it again?